# get dropdown value on ng-change in angularjs with static values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get value when I change the dropdown on ng-change. My code as follows:-

```
<select class="form-control" id="cobSRQ2" ng-change="cobchange()" required>
    <option>[Select One]</option>
    <option value="Primary" selected>Primary</option>
    <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
    <option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option>
</select>
```

I want to send the value to Angular JS controller.

Please help

Comment: what have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value when selected ng-option changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016565/get-value-when-selected-ng-option-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-model for pass the value :

```
 app.controller('controllername',function($scope){
 $scope.drpmodel=-1
 $scope.cobchange=function(){

     alert($scope.drpmodel);

  }


 });

 <select class="form-control" id="cobSRQ2" ng-model="drpmodel" ng-change="cobchange()" required>
   <option value="-1">[Select One]</option>
   <option value="Primary" selected>Primary</option>
   <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
   <option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option>
</select>
```

Comment: undefined is coming in alert message

Comment: try changing ng-model="drpmodel"  ng-change="cobchange(drpmodel)"

Comment: I am getting the value but my dropdown first value is shown as blank

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: ok leave all thing just do one last thing :
 <option value="-1" selected> [Select One]</option>

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `ng-model` attribute to `<select>` and pass it in the `ng-change` function like:

```
<select ng-model="cob" class="form-control" id="cobSRQ2" ng-change="cobchange(cob)" required>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

for ng-change to work you must provide ng-model to select

```
<select class="form-control" id="cobSRQ2" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="cobchange()"    required>
<option>[Select One]</option>
<option value="Primary" selected>Primary</option>
<option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
<option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option>
</select>
```

inside controller

```
$scope.cobchange=function(){
console.log($scope.myModel);
          }
```

Comment: do one thing initialize $scope.myModel={}; in the controller and try @rahul