# How can I bind the value of the selected item to 2 models

Tags: angularjs

Currently when the user selects an item from the DDL, the Id will be set to my model `vm.Blah.Id`

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Blah">Blah blah</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="blah"  ng-change="vm.LoadBlahs()" ng-model="vm.Blah.Id">
        <option value="">Select some Blah</option>
        <option ng-repeat="m in vm.BlahList" value="{{m.BlahId}}">{{m.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When a DDL item is selected, I need to do this somehow:

```
vm.Blah.Id = m.BlahId;
vm.OtherBlah.SectionId = m.SectionId;
```

How can I update 2 things like that?

I'm on version 1.5.8

Comment: Why would you need to manually set `vm.Blah.Id = m.BlahId`. That is what happens by default when you select an item.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to re-work some of your code but a possible solution would be:

1. Change `ng-model` to be a new variable that holds the selected item.
2. Pass the `ng-model` (in your case `m`) as an argument to the `ng-change` function (See
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017098/1729686 for how to do this).
3. Update the things in the `ng-change` function.