# Assign option's description to a variable on select

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-options to populate my select. I assign the value to be the id of the field however I need to assign the description of my option as well.

Not sure how to do that **without** iterating through my list separately afterwards to find the matching id.

So I am assigning the user's id to the `vm.model.user` but how can I possibly assign name to a different variable and still make this generic. The key part is this being generic as the description name might vary (sometimes it's description or userDescription etc. and I cannot control that).

```js
$scope.users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Adam' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Chloe' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Chris' }
];
```

```html
<select ng-model="vm.model.user" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
```

I have tried doing this on `ng-change` but it seems it is not aware of `user`, only `ng-options` is.

`ng-change="vm.model.userDescription = user.name"`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set `ng-model` with the the selected user object, so `vm.model.user` would have both id and name:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model.user" ng-options="user as user.name for user in vm.users | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
```

Check demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s75nfbdh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28323031/9559251

Basically we could just do

`ng-change="vm.model.userDescription = (users | filter: {id: vm.model.user})[0].name"`

Comment: Not sure if I should ever care about the efficiency of running a filter on the list of options as it doesn't look like the 'cleanest' solution.